# Finding array items PHP

Tags: php, arrays, output

I have gone code blind and don't know how to get the results I need to output values in a desired format.

I have a search function on an internal website which queries MSSQL based on multiple strings. For instance if a user enters "CCENT MCSE" the query will return all users with that have either certification accredited to them.

To be clear this will return all users who have CCENT cerfificate OR MCSE

My boss now want to change this to AND by using an operator (+) sign so when a user enters "CCENT+MCSE" the query should return users who have the CCENT AND MCSE certification.

The way I have built the query is to explode the search string into an array referencing the + sign as the delimiter.

My SQL statement pulls back the following result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [username] => mshort
        [fname] => Matthew
        [lname] => Short
        [location_name] => CENTRAL REMOTE
        [grade_name] => E6
        [skill_name] => CCENT
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [username] => mark.parry
        [fname] => Mark
        [lname] => Parry
        [location_name] => CENTRAL OFFICE
        [grade_name] => E4
        [skill_name] => MCSE Messaging
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [username] => mark.parry
        [fname] => Mark
        [lname] => Parry
        [location_name] => CENTRAL OFFICE
        [grade_name] => E4
        [skill_name] => CCENT
    )

)
```

What needs to happen in this case is I need to display only unique users who have both CCENT AND MCSE and discard the users who only have one of them.

In the above example I need to output only Mark Parry and discard Matthew Short

I am not sure how to do it. Please can you help?

Thanks

The SQL Statement

```
SELECT username,fname,lname,el.location_name, eg.grade_name,el.location_name
,sl.skill_nameFROM engineer e 
INNER JOIN engineer_skills es ON e.id=es.engineer_id INNER JOIN skills_list sl ON    es.skill_id=sl.id 
INNER JOIN engineer_grades eg ON e.grade=eg.id 
INNER JOIN    engineer_location el ON e.location=el.id INNER JOIN team t ON e.team=t.id
WHERE e.id > 0 AND '.$sql_where.' ORDER BY lname'
```

$sql_where is this
     sl.skill_name LIKE   '%".$search[$i]."%' OR

and I strip the last OR

Comment: What does the query look like?

Comment: Why aren't you using quotes around the values?

Comment: It would be helpful to show your table structure and the SQL you're generating

Comment: rather then trying to play with the results, just alter the query to `AND`.

Comment: My SQL Statement is this
'SELECT username,fname,lname,el.location_name, eg.grade_name,el.location_name,sl.skill_name FROM engineer e
     INNER JOIN engineer_skills es ON e.id=es.engineer_id
     INNER JOIN skills_list sl ON es.skill_id=sl.id
     INNER JOIN engineer_grades eg ON e.grade=eg.id
     INNER JOIN engineer_location el ON e.location=el.id
     INNER JOIN team t ON e.team=t.id
     WHERE 
     e.id > 0 AND '.$sql_where.' ORDER BY lname'

$sql_where is this sl.skill_name LIKE '%".$search[$i]."%' OR and I strip the last OR

Comment: I tried adding AND but returns no result

Comment: Add sql query to original question please.  Easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array (assuming it is names `$data`)

First, emulate group by username

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $item) {
  if(!isset($result[$item["username"]])) $result[$item["username"]] = $item;
  else $result[$item["username"]]["skill_name"].="+".$item["skill_name"];
}
```

Second, filter the result

```
$filter = array("CCENT","MCSE");
function skill_and_filter($item) {
  global $filter;
  foreach($filter as $f) if(strpos($item["skill_name"],$f)===false) return false;
  return true;
}

$result = array_filter($result,"skill_and_filter");
```